# Window.prompt accept only numeric values

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying (unsuccessfully although) to make a window.prompt which will accept ***only*** numeric values (0,1,2,3,...) but I believe that something I am doing wrong. Look at my function. Am I missunderstanding something? how can i use this regex `/^[0-9.,]+$/` in my code?

```
<script>
    function save3() {
      var pn = 4; 
      do{
        var selection = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the User Id:", "Type a number!"), 10);
if (selection != (/^[0-9.,]+$/)){
    window.alert("xana");       
    }
        }while(isNaN(selection));
    $("#user_id").val(selection)
      //$("#user_id").val(prompt("Give the User Id:"))
      do{
        var selection2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the Book Id:", "Type a number!"), 10);
        }while(isNaN(selection2));
    $("#book_id").val(selection2)
      //$("#book_id").val(prompt("Give the Book Id:"))
      do{
        var selection3 = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the Game Id:", "Type a number!"), 10);
        }while(isNaN(selection3));
    $("#game_id").val(selection3)
      //$("#game_id").val(prompt("Give the Game Id:"))
      $("#site_id").val(pn)
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You need to use the regex to test against the result of `prompt`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you. I did it but i have another problem now. When a user type , for example 4f, i want my code to not accept it the input. Any ideas? I've updated also my try above with your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce the issue, e.g.:

```js
 var selection = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the User Id:", "Type a number!"), 10);

if (selection != (/^[0-9.,]+$/)){
  console.log('fail');
} else {
  console.log('pass');
}
```

This returns "fail" for any value because you're testing a number against a regular expression object, which can never be equal.

If you want the user to only enter digits, period (.) and comma (,), then leave the entered text as a string and test it using the *test* method. I've also inverted the test so it makes more sense:

```js
var selection = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the User Id:", "Type a number!"), 10);

if ( /^[0-9.,]+$/.test(selection)) {
  console.log('pass');

} else {
  console.log('fail');
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. The best solution around here! It works!

Comment: if i wanted to exclude everything else on my keyboard (except from numbers) how the reg will be changed?

Comment: If you want one or more digits only, the regular expression can be `/^\d+$/`, or you can reverse the test and look for anything that isn't a digit `/\D/`, but that will allow an empty string (since it doesn't contain any non–digits).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check your input like:

```
const isInteger = /^(\d)+$/g;
if(isInteger.test(selection)) {
  console.log('Correct input!');
  // ... code
}
```