# iIf the number is not a number, show the message again. In JS

Tags: javascript

I have This code

```
let firstname = window.prompt('Enter ur Firstname');
let lastname = window.prompt('Enter ur Lastname');
let age = window.prompt('Enter ur Age');
console.log('Hello' + firstname + lastname + ' ' + 'and your age is' + ' ' + age);
```

But in the "Age" section, the user can also enter a string.
What can I do to prevent the user from creating a string?
For example:
User entered a string.
Show message titled "Age entered is not a number"
And the message is displayed again until the user enters a number.
Thank you for helping me ...

Comment: Everything you're getting from `promp` is string. You've to convert the return value to number, and then check if you got a number from the conversion.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window.prompt accept only numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553230/window-prompt-accept-only-numeric-values)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### You need some sort of loop, to keep taking you back to the age input

The simplest way to structure this is with a `while` loop. You can test each time, whether `age` is valid. For simplicity, I am simply testing whether it is greater than 0. This means that 0, although a number, will be rejected, as it is unlikely that a person is actually aged 0 and yet somehow answering the question.

If you are using a `while` loop, you need to set up a value for age in advance, which you know to be invalid. That will allow the `while` to test the condition on the first go of the loop, and see that it is not valid, and ask the age.

The code below accepts any number greater than 0 as a valid age.

I've also added a little piece of code that creates an error message that can be fed back to the user.

```js
let firstname = window.prompt('Enter ur Firstname');
let lastname = window.prompt('Enter ur Lastname');

let age = "invalid"
let errorMessage = ""
while (!(age > 0)) {
  age = window.prompt(errorMessage + 'Enter ur Age');
  errorMessage = '"' + age + '" is not a number. '
}

console.log('Hello' + firstname + ' ' + lastname + ' ' + 'and your age is' + ' ' + age);
```